# Install MySQL Workbench in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mysql-workbench

**I tried to install MySQL Workbench by:**

```
apt-get install mysql-workbench-community
```

But I get the following errors and I am unable to install it manually:

Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
Depends: libzip5 (>= 0.10) but it is not installable

How can I install it?

Answer (score 2):

Doing this worked for me:

```
snap install mysql-workbench-community
```